# What is '-' in front of a column in mysql mean?

Tags: mysql, union

What is the significance of "-" (Last line of the code, before a.emp_no) in the following code? I have been trying to understand but I want sure answers. Please Help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT
    e.emp_no,
    e.first_name,
    e.last_name,
    NULL AS dept_no,
    NULL AS from_date
FROM
    employees.employees e
WHERE
    last_name = 'Denis' 
UNION SELECT
    NULL AS emp_no,
    NULL AS first_name,
    NULL AS last_name,
    dm.dept_no,
    dm.from_date
FROM
   employees.dept_manager dm) as a
ORDER BY -a.emp_no DESC;
```

Comment: You could test the difference between `ORDER BY -a.emp_no DESC` and `ORDER BY a.emp_no` and you'll probably find out that the biggest difference is how null values are handled, that is, where null values appear in the output. But I wouldn't expect employee number to be null allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if emp_no is a number - then it is asking to order by the negative of the number.  you could also say

```
order by a.emp_no
```